# How to detect 404 url and make this link underline or change background color?

Tags: plugins, functions, 404-error

```
<a id="block_bell" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/email-newsletter"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Get New Posts Notification</a>
```

if this page is not exist or redirect to 404 page, then make this text `Get New Posts Notification` background red.

Comment: Hi @Protik could you please explain the problem in somewhat more detail?

Comment: Are you asking to check the source of the HREF of the A link to see if it is a 404?

Comment: 1) Where is the code part placed? In which template? 2) Is it correct that you want it in red, if the get_home_url() does not exist? Do I correctly understand that?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got the sollution.